# Why when I try to print an attribute from base clase ,it is always 0 ? in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, printing, derived-class

I have a base class

```
class Servicii{
protected:
    double price;
public:
    Servicii(double p):price(p){}
    double getPrice(){return price;}
```

and 3 derived classes `Car` `Book` `House`.Because they are derived class,all of them will have *a price*

```
class House:public Servicii{
private:
    int level;
public:
    House(double p,int l):
          Servicii(price),level(l){}
```

And in main I create some objects like this:

```
House *h1=new House(600,3);
Book *b1=new Book("Dostoievski","Crima si Pedeapsa",5,98.5);
```

My problem is that when i print the price is always 0 .For example the house has the price 600,but when i printed it it is 0 and i don't know why.
I've made a print function in Servicii and all dervied classes inherits this function+ they print their own attributes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Servicii(p)` in the member intializer of `House`? Please provide a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just looks like a typo, but is the typo in this post, or in the actual code?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. Any compiler should give you a warning about not using `p`. Clang helpfully [points out the use of an uninitialized variable](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/y7ovrD).

Answer (score 3):

In this constructor:

```
House(double p,int l):
          Servicii(price),level(l){}
```

you are using the base class member `price` to initialize `Servicii`. This is incorrect, and it is in fact undefined behavior to access this member before the base class has been initialized completely.

You just need to use the value `p` to initialize `Servicii` instead:

```
House(double p,int l):
          Servicii(p),level(l){}
```

If you turn on compiler warnings, you will be warned about making these kinds of mistakes.